# A random sample has been taken from a normal dist. and the conf. intervals using the same data: (38.02, 61.98) and (39.95, 60.05)

Tags: statistics

What is the value of the sample mean?
) One of these intervals is 99% confidence interval and the other is a 95% confidence interval. Which one is
the 95% confidence interval and why?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on another entry on Chegg. The approach is similar.
Sample mean from the first confidence interval $= \frac{38.02+61.98}2 = 50$.
Sample mean from the second confidence interval $=\frac{39.95+60.05}2 = 50$
The $99\%$ CI is $(35.59, 51.81)$ and the $95\%$ CI is $(37.53, 49.87)$.
The higher the confidence level, the wider the CI.